# Date calculations in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

When given a start date a need to do various calculations on it to produce 3 other dates.

Basically I need to work out what date the user has been billed up to for different frequencies based on the current date.

Bi-Annually (billed twice a year),
Quarterly (billed 4 times a year),
and Two Monthly (billed ever other month).

Take the date 26/04/2008
- BiAnnually: This date would have been last billed on 26/10/2010 and should give the date 26/04/2011.
- Quarterly: This date would have been last billed on 26/01/2011 and should give the date 26/04/2011.
- Two Month: This date would have been last billed on 26/12/2010 and should give the date 26/02/2011.

Assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could achieve what you want with Fluent Datetime (http://fluentdatetime.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Lots of things should be considered. This post by Jon Skeet may be interesting to you [The joys of date/time arithmetic](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic.aspx)

Comment: You have a start date, you have an interval. Seems reasonable to start adding the interval and compare it to the current date. Keep doing this until the date exceeds current date, then keep the last date and the greater than date. See where this gets you, then ask if it can be done better or if you're missing an important detail.

Comment: Bi-annually means ever two years. What you mean is semi-annually.

Comment: @Joel: see *biennially.* Biannual is correct here.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Thanks for that update. Apparently it means both, though biennially is more semantically correct.

Comment: @alpha-mouse your link to Jon Skeet's post is dead.

Comment: @SteveB thanks, this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic/ should stay alive for longer, I hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can just do like this:

```
public void FindNextDate(DateTime startDate, int interval);
  DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
  do {
    startDate = startDate.AddMonths(interval);
  } while (startDate <= today);
  return startDate;
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2008, m4, 26);

DateTime bi = FindNextDate(startDate, 6);
DateTime quarterly = FindNextDate(startDate, 3);
DateTime two = FindNextDate(startDate, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you want is something like

```
DateTime x = YourDateBasis;
y = x.AddMonths(6);
y = x.AddMonths(3);
y = x.AddMonths(2);
```

Then to edit from comment,

Date Math per the period cycle of the person's account, you would simply need the start and end date and keep adding respective months until you've created all expected months.  Almost like that of a loan payment that's due every month for 3 years

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
while( CurrentDate < YourFinalDateInFuture )
{
   CurrentDate = CurrentDate.AddMonths( CycleFrequency );
   Add Record into your table as needed
   Perform other calcs as needed
}
```

Comment: Given the sample date: 26/04/2008, that would give me the result 26/10/2008 (AddMonths(6)), i need to calculate the number of times to add 6 months.

Comment: what about start date , current date and calculate the number of months in between? Then divide that number by 6 or 3 or 2 and you know the number of past billing cycles.

Comment: @Anthony, revised the answer posting

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, I know bi-annually, but based on his provided dates was semi-annually 6 months.  The principles of the math he would be able to get right away, just applying simple date-math principles to him.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum BillPeriod
{
   TwoMonth = 2,
   Quarterly = 3,
   SemiAnnually = 6,
   BiAnnually = 24
}

public Pair<Datetime, Datetime> BillDates(Datetime currentBillDate, BillPeriod period)
{
   Datetime LastBill = currentBillDate.AddMonths(-1 * (int)period);
   Datetime NextBill = currentBillDate.AddMonths((int)period);
   return new Pair<Datetime,Datetime>(LastBill, NextBill);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible solution, but it works.  Remember, red-light, green-light, refactor.  Here, we're at green-light:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(GetLastBilled(new DateTime(2008, 4, 26), 6));
            Console.WriteLine(GetNextBilled(new DateTime(2008, 4, 26), 6));

            Console.WriteLine(GetLastBilled(new DateTime(2008, 4, 26), 4));
            Console.WriteLine(GetNextBilled(new DateTime(2008, 4, 26), 4));

            Console.WriteLine(GetLastBilled(new DateTime(2008, 4, 26), 2));
            Console.WriteLine(GetNextBilled(new DateTime(2008, 4, 26), 2));

            Console.WriteLine("Complete...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static DateTime GetLastBilled(DateTime initialDate, int billingInterval) {
            // strip time and handle staggered month-end and 2/29
            var result = initialDate.Date.AddYears(DateTime.Now.Year - initialDate.Year);
            while (result > DateTime.Now.Date) {
                result = result.AddMonths(billingInterval * -1);
            }
            return result;
        }

        static DateTime GetNextBilled(DateTime initialDate, int billingInterval) {
            // strip time and handle staggered month-end and 2/29
            var result = initialDate.Date.AddYears(DateTime.Now.Year - initialDate.Year);
            while (result > DateTime.Now.Date) {
                result = result.AddMonths(billingInterval * -1);
            }
            result = result.AddMonths(billingInterval);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This is really tricky.  For example, you need to take into account that the date you billed could have been 2/29 on a leap year, and not all months have the same number of days.  That's why I did the `initialDate.Date.AddYears(DateTime.Now.Year - initialDate.Year);` call.